# Excel Hyperlink - jump to cell and scroll window

Tags: excel, hyperlink

I am working in excel and I want to make a Hyper Link from the top of the page to another location on the page.

I type in a box at the top, and then right link and go down to `hyper link` in the dropdown menu I click it and select the tab that says "In This Work Book" and change it to where I want it to go. So all this is good and all but my Question is:

> Can I make a Hyper link to bring me to a cell and scroll the window so the selected cell is the first row, instead of being near the bottom of the window?

Example:

Hyper link: "Test" Located in Cell A,1

Location Of Hyper Link: A,210

Now instead of having it put A,210 at the very Bottom and show the cells above it, I want to to be at the top and show the cells below it.

Thanks for the help,

Comment: Yes at the top of my screen instead of the bottom So I would want Cell A,210 to be at the top and not bottom

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Add the following VBA code to your worksheet:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_FollowHyperlink(ByVal Target As Hyperlink)
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = ActiveCell.Row
End Sub
```

By magic, when you click a link, that cell will be at the top. If you don't want this behavior for all links, you can test the `Target` address.

You will have to save the code as a `xlsm` file so that macros are enabled. Use `Alt-F-11` to open the VBA editor so you can actually add the code (double click the worksheet in the left hand pane, then paste the above code in the window that opens).

Comment: You are the man Thanks Answered and Rep if i Find out how. Also where did you learn that.

Comment: I googled "excel hyperlink anchor scroll to top" - the second link took me to a site that had a version of the answer. I adapted it from there.

Comment: You are very welcome! I also learn a lot just by hanging around on StackOverflow... :-)

Comment: It appears to work only text hyperlinks not on shapes.
But it does the job.

Many thanks for that

Comment: It really is magical... worked perfectly even though I'm using frozen rows - it scrolls perfectly to the top of the frozen pane.