# Make the anchor address the upper left cell in active window when Excel Hyperlink to another tab is clicked

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel workbook with a table of contents tab that has hyperlinks to other tabs and different locations on those tabs i.e. names and regions.

My question is, how can I get it to where no matter what hyperlink I click on, it will go to that tab and the cell will always appear in the upper left corner instead of the lower right.  Excel by default makes the target cell upper left in the active window, but this is not the case when the target cell is in the active window.

I am trying to make it easier for the end user so they will not have to keep scrolling to that section to get it in view.  Thank you in advance.

Comment: You might consider including a `Worksheet.Activate` function in each worksheet that will automatically scroll itself to the activecell in that sheet

Comment: you need to provide a sample since you are confusing everyone here

Comment: @Ibo I dropped an answer below.

Comment: I actually made a demo and this is the default behavior, everytime I click on the hyperlink, the target becomes the upper left cell, so there must be some other event macros or sth that distorts this behavior, that means we need to see the workbook or a sample of it

Comment: @Ibo for me that’s only true when the linked cell was not already in the active part of the window. If I link to a cell that’s just like a single column it just offsets and doesn’t reset the scroll

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Slight Addition to: [Excel-Hyperlink-Jump-to-cell-and-scroll-window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19127549/excel-hyperlink-jump-to-cell-and-scroll-window)

Place this code in your Table of Contents sheet.  Any Hyperlink on your ToC sheet will go to the tab, and scroll to the row and column of the hyperlinks destination.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_FollowHyperlink(ByVal Target As Hyperlink)
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = ActiveCell.Row
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = ActiveCell.Column
End Sub
```

Comment: @ChrisSchaeuble consider accepting this as the 'best answer' if you feel it solved your problem :)

Answer (score 2):

When the user clicks a link and it sends them to a sheet, the cell that is linked to becomes the `ActiveCell`. If you include this in every cell that will be linked to, it will auto-scroll to the desired cell when the link is clicked.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    Application.Goto ActiveCell, True
End Sub
```

The only caveat would be that for occasions where a user might instead click on a cell manually with no intention of scrolling to that cell, it will do so next time the sheet is activated

Comment: Ah that's a lot simpler, I didn't realise it became the ActiveCell. I guess it would be more efficient to place it in the WorkbookSheetActivate event.

Comment: This answer most definitely meets the OP requirement, but I think that "feature" would eventually become annoying in most use-cases as the sheet would jump around unexpectedly as they navigated between sheets Just my two cents.

Comment: I think if you could isolate this to only occur when previous sheet value = table of contents, that would be pretty solid. You'd probably need a global variable to capture last sheet name and have a procedure run after each sheet was deactivated, then cross check it with each sheet when activated.

Too much work for me to do (for free) on a Monday, but fun to think about. Good luck.

Comment: @PGCideRider, ah that’s a good way to solve that thank you for the idea!

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Insert -> Add HyperLink -> Same document (you can specified any cell)

If you mean Anchor in WorkSheet :-)

Comment: This is close but does not answer the question - the user wants the window to scroll the linked cell to the top of the screen when the links are clicked

Answer (score 0):

If you put this in the sheet activate event R40 will be the top left cell so perhaps you can work with that?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    Application.Goto Range("R40"), True
End Sub
```

To take a stage further, this would work if your hyperlinked cells all contained sheet name ! cell address , e.g. Sheet2!R40. The code goes in the sheet module.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_FollowHyperlink(ByVal Target As Hyperlink)

Dim v

v = Split(Replace(Target.SubAddress, "'", ""), "!")
Application.Goto Sheets(v(0)).Range(v(1)), True

End Sub
```

Comment: If you change the range to `ActiveCell` it will work as intended

Answer (score 0):

If you understand how to use VBA with events, this should do what you want.

It includes a defense against sheets with spaces in them.

```
Sub JumpToPostion()
Dim WS As Worksheet, CellAddress As String
    Set WS = Sheet2
    CellAddress = "z100"

    Application.Goto Range(FixSheet(WS.Name) & "!" & CellAddress), Scroll:=True

End Sub

Private Function FixSheet(txt As String) As String
    If InStr(1, txt, " ") > 0 Then
        FixSheet = "'" & txt & "'"
    Else
        FixSheet = txt
    End If

End Function
```