# Jump to Active Cell with Hyperlink Formula

Tags: excel, vba

I've got a very horizontally long worksheet and I've created hyperlinks using the hyperlink formula and a match formula that matches to section headings. I've found some VBA code that jumps the window to the active cell but I can only get this to work if hyperlink cells using the (ctrl+k) method. Is there a way to jump the window to the active cell following a link from the hyperlink formula?

Original reference I've been using. [Excel Hyperlink - jump to cell and scroll window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19127549/excel-hyperlink-jump-to-cell-and-scroll-window#comment28286721_19127669)

Thanks!

Comment: The `FollowHyperlink` event doesn't fire with hyperlinks created using a hyperlink formula.

Comment: Is there a way to make the hyperlink dynamic (e.g., move location in sheet if a user adds/deletes a column) without using the hyperlink formula?

Comment: .... using named range to make hyperlink dynamic. Thanks for the help! Thought the macro wasn't working for me.